# Joining on rows (Combining datasets from two different sources) in PIg

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose I have two datasets

```
ID Name
1 Dog
2 Cat
```

and another data set

```
ID Name Age
3 Man 23
```

I load both into pig, and drop the age field from the second, now how do I combine the two so that I get

```
Id Name
1 Dog
2 Cat
3 Man
```

They can be distributed across mappers and added to any mapper in any order.  I just want them to be together so I can perform a sort like operation (removing duplication and fetching the most recent timestamp) in the next map-reduce phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
set1 = load 'dataset1' as (ID,Name);
set2 = load 'dataset2' as (ID,Name,Age);
set3 = foreach set2 generate ID,Name;

Result = UNION set1,set3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#union

As you can see in the examples, you don't need to remove Age field from set2
But if you want, just use `GENERATE`

```
set3 = foreach set2 GENERATE Id, Name.

set4 = set1 UNION set3
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

set1 = load 'dataset1' as (ID,Name);

set2 = load 'dataset2' as (ID,Name,Age);

set3 = foreach set2 generate ID,Name;

Result = UNION set1,set3;

but the output order may changes

But when u dump , you may get

Id Name

3 Man

1 Dog

2 Cat

order will change when we perform UNION in pig, for the above data you may not find any difference but when we perform union for more than two files the order changes .